# Slashes in ggplot2 legend- geom_point and geom_abline together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know I'm not the first to ask a question in this arena but I haven't been able to figure out the solution to my particular quandary. Here's a stripped-down example of my problem.

```
    data<-data.frame(Est=c(1:20,1:20),Measured=c(1:5,5:9,1:6,3:6,1:6,3:6,1:4,4,4:8),variable=c(rep("Plot1",20),rep("Plot2",20)))

p<-ggplot(data,aes(y=Est,x=Measured,shape=variable))
p<- p + geom_point(stat="identity") +coord_fixed(xlim=c(0,25),ylim=c(0,25)) + theme_bw() 

p #If you plot the figure at this point, the points stand alone in the legend
p<-p+ geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1,aes(linetype="1:1",color="1:1"),show_guide=TRUE)

p # Once the geom_abline is added, there are lines through the points. :(

p<-p+scale_color_manual(name="Lines",
                        values=c("1:1"="black"))
p<- p + scale_linetype_manual(name="Lines",
                              values=c("1:1"=2))              

p<-p + scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,20), name = "")

p<- p+xlab(expression(paste("Measured volume(",ducks^{3},"",ha^{-1},")",sep=""))) 
p<-p+ ylab(expression(paste("Estimated volume (",ducks^{3},"",ha^{-1},")",sep="")))
```

As you can see, the legend for the points includes slashes (which I think are actually a line), and I would really prefer that the points were alone.

While the example code has only 1 line and linetype, the actual figure I've made includes five different lines of varying colors and linetypes, and thus I need a solution that allows me to include multiple geom_abline calls with color and linetype specified.

And no, I'm not really measuring the volume of anything in ducks, although that would be really entertaining to study...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the aesthetic mapping:

```
p + guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

I always end up trying to override aesthetics by setting them to `NULL`, but for some reason that intuition is usually wrong.